# Converter função de recursiva para iterativa

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Tenho uma função de mesclagem de listas encadeadas funcionando. Porém, está sendo usado recursão e eu gostaria de mudar o código e fazer iterativo. Porém, não obtive êxito.

Segue o código:

```
struct Node
 {
 int data;
 struct Node *next;
 }

struct Node* MergeLists(struct Node *headA,struct Node* headB)
{
if(headA==NULL) return headB;
if(headB==NULL) return headA;
if(headA==NULL && headB==NULL) return NULL;

if(headA->data < headB->data)
{
    headA->next=MergeLists(headA->next,headB);
   return headA;
}
else 
{
    headB->next=MergeLists(headA,headB->next);
    return headB;
}
}
```

O que eu consegui até agora foi isso:

```
 struct Node
 {
 int data;
 struct Node *next;
 }

  Node* MergeLists(Node *headA, Node* headB)
 {
 if(headA==NULL) return headB;
 if(headB==NULL) return headA;
 if(headA==NULL && headB==NULL) return NULL;
 while(headA!=NULL && headB!=NULL)
 {
    if(headA->data>headB->data)
    {
        return headB;
        headB=headB->next;/*O problema está aqui preciso retornar o valor menor e ao mesmo tempo avançar a lista*/
    }else 
    {
        return headA;
        headA=headA->next;/*O problema está aqui preciso retornar o valor menor e ao mesmo tempo avançar a lista com o return antes ele irá sair sem avançar*/
    }        
    }
    }
```

OBS: As duas listas estão em ordem crescente.

Ex:

> HeadA = 1, 3, 5.
>
> HeadB = 2, 4, 6.
>
> Mesclagem = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.

Comment: Mistura "ordenado"? Se as duas listas estiverem previamente ordenadas, a nova então é ordenada?

Comment: Olá @JeffersonQuesado sim estão previamente ordenadas, a nova vai ser ordenada. Mas no caso só tem que retornar  o menor até acabar a lista. Tipo assim compara HeadA com headB, se headA for menor retorna headA e depois tem que ser headB obrigatóriamente, depois avança a lista e compara novamente.

Answer (score 2):

Empilhadas, as chamadas no código são. Ao desempilhar, os nós das listas religados. De trás-para-frente, no seu código original, mesclada a lista . Na pilha de chamadas, os nós a serem ligados, armazenados. Sem conceito de pilha e sem mudanças drásticas, o algoritmo original, iterativo não dá para fazer.

Para o algoritmo iterativo você deve ter necessariamente uma nova abordagem:

Você deve criar uma nova lista. Dela, a cabeça e a cauda, irá manter em variáveis. De frente-para-trás sim, de trás-para-frente não, a nova lista. Os nós de `headA` e `headB`, em cada iteração, de suas listas você deve retirar  e à cauda da sua nova lista você irá adicionar. Até que  ambas as listas fiquem vazias.

O código, ele aqui está:

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
}

struct Node* MergeLists(struct Node *headA, struct Node* headB) {
    if (headA == NULL) return headB;
    if (headB == NULL) return headA;
    struct Node *headC = NULL;
    struct Node *tailC = NULL;

    while (headA != NULL || headB != NULL) {
        if (headB == NULL || headA->data < headB->data) {
            if (headC == NULL) {
                tailC = headC = headA;
            } else {
                tailC->prox = headA;
                tailC = headA;
            }
            headA = headA->prox;
        } else {
            if (headC == NULL) {
                tailC = headC = headB;
            } else {
                tailC->prox = headB;
                tailC = headB;
            }
            headB = headB->prox;
        }
    }
    return headC;
}
```

Comment: O primeiro if tem headB==NULL e no while tem headB!=NULL. Está certo?

Comment: @YODA Sim está correto. Observe que no `while` temos `||` e não `&&`. No caso de `headA` não ser `NULL`, mas `headB` ser `NULL`, ele tem que entrar no `if`. No caso de `headA` ser `NULL`, mas `headA` ser `NULL`, ele tem que entrar no `else`. Se os dois forem `NULL`, ele tem que sair do `while`. Se nenhum for `NULL` ele tem que comparar.

Comment: Bá agora que vi o || no while. Entendi. Muito obrigado!